# dataTransfer getData and setData in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a React Application and seem to be coming across an issue in IE and Edge whereby the follow lines of code seem to be throwing out errors:

**Error (1)**

**Message:** `Element not found.`

**Code:**

```
onDragStart={event => { 
    event.dataTransfer.setData('storm-diagram-node', JSON.stringify(this.props.model));
}}
```

**Error (2)**

**Message:** `JSON.parse Error: Unexpected input at position:0`

**Code:**

```
onDrop={event => {
    var data = JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData('storm-diagram-node'));
}}
```

Now this application works perfectly in Chrome but for some reason not IE or Edge. These both seem like the same issue and is why they are in the same question.

Comment: Does getData return a string or an object?

Comment: @JosanIracheta String

Answer (score 2):

`setData` and `getData` do not work with custom MIME types.

See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8007622/.

Comment: Upvoted but actually what they don't say is that it works only with **one** custom parameter: `"text"`; the real MIME type `"text/plain"` being unsupported in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little piece of code i found in my Toolbox. Checked in EDGE.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
<title>12 hour Time and Date stamp</title>
<meta name="" content="">
<style>
    .thing {
  width: 100px;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
 }
.col {
  width: 130px;
  height: 450px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  }
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var origThing = document.getElementById(data);
  var newThing = origThing.cloneNode(true);
    ev.target.appendChild(newThing);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col" id="col1">
  <div class="thing" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="thing1">THING 1</div>
  <div class="thing" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="thing2">THING 2</div>  
  <div class="thing" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="thing3">THING 3</div>  
  <div class="thing" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="thing4">THING 4</div>
</div>
<div class="col" id="col2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you could pass an object as a string with `text` param in `setData`:

```
var obj = {'x': 5, 'y': 10};
var objS = JSON.stringify(obj);
e.dataTransfer.setData("text", objS);
```

On the other side, extract the data:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
console.log("obj:", obj.x + ", " + obj.y);
```